# Codeigniter and PHP. Check format of POST item with regex?

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I am developing an API using Codeigniter an Phils RESTserver.
In one of the resources the developer can send in an "array" of email addresses
that then gets processed on the server.

How can I, perhaps using regex, check that the incoming "array" is in the format
as you can see below? I will use this as a CI Form validation.

```
("email@example.com","anna@nicole.com")
```

Thankful for all help!

Comment: Again, maybe it would be much more convenient to pass an array, rather than pass this custom string, validate it with regexes and split into array?

Comment: How will that be done? The validation and the format of the array.

Comment: Post your code that perfroms backend request. Without knowing how you are sending requests little can be done.

Comment: I am posting through Firefox plugin RestClient. On the server side I got this http://pastie.org/private/xsc4be8pkiugls4wroiuvq

Comment: Well, if you are posting it in request body like `addresses ("email@example.com","anna@nicole.com")` you may replace it with `addresses[] "email@example.com" *newline* addresses[] "anna@nicole.com"`, so you'll be able to extract this with `$_POST['addresses']` as an array. Alternative syntax `addresses ["email@example.com","anna@nicole.com"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($this->post('emails') as $email)
{
     if ( ! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
     {
         return $this->response(array('message' => 'GTFO'), 400);
     }
}
```